# Smartgit: Repository Suddenly missing

Tags: repository, smartgit

Smartgit has decided that my repository is somehow misssing from my hard drive.
The repo that is definitely not missing, its exactly where i left it, nothing has changed as far as i'm aware. The repository i've been using for six months and made over 100 pull requests from.

If i rightclick the repository in the Repositories panel, and select Settings, it brings up a file selection window, presumably expecting me to tell it where the repo is.
When i do so, by clicking Select Folder in the folder its already in, it seems to reject this and brings up the window again, infinitely.  It will not accept me telling it that the repository is exactly where its always been and still is

https://i.imgur.com/VLjOSHu.gif

I have no idea what's going on here, please help

Comment: Can you remove the repository from the list of repositories and _then_ readd it?

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar issue just now. I think the answer/clue is already there in your screen capture with SmartGit warning down the bottom right corner.

I ran `git gc` manually in command prompt and all went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `%userprofile%/.gitconfig` was misconfigured. I discovered this when I tried to run `git.exe init` and it said there was an error on a line in that file.